# Azure Data Factory pipeline not working using cosmos DB while we use derived column expression builder,its not take morethan 19 column

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I have a csv file with comma delimeter.I tried to insert these file file data to cosmos databse.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

This is my expression builder:-
@(A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D,E=E,F=F,G=G,H=H,I=I,J=J,K=K,L=L,M=M,N=N,O=O,P=P,Q=Q,R=R,S=S,T=T,U=U,V=V)
When i used upto 15 its working means upto O.If i used all value its not working.Pipeline is runing infinetly,I have check upto 4hours stil pipeline running.File contains only one row.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this and faced the same issue despite increasing the data flow runtime cores. But you can try this **alternate workaround** for this.

First **Transform the csv file into new container of blob storage as a JSON** file. Then use a **copy activity to copy it to azure cosmos db**.

Create a JSON dataset with the new container but **without any filename** as dataflow will create part JSON file in the container and give it Dataflow sink.

[image]

Now, in the pipeline use **copy activity** and give the **same JSON dataset as source** for it. Use wildcard path to specify JSON files (`*.json`)as we can have only one file that is JSON generated from dataflow.

[image]

Give the **cosmos db dataset as sink for copy activity**. After execution, it will create a JSON file in the blob then copies this content to cosmos db.

**JSON file in blob:**

[image]

**Cosmos db data:**

[image]

***NOTE:***  This approach **might also result as InProgress** if you are using the same Azure Integration runtime for the **dataflow debug** with small cores.

In that case try to create a new Azure integration run time with higher cores and use it for dataflow debug.
Please check [How to create and configure Azure Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory).

After creation, go to Monitor and click on it and change the cores like this and check with dataflow.

[image]

Change runtime to this in the **dataflow settings of the pipeline** and in the **dataflow debug** as well.