# Can CosmosDB partial document updates can be done in ADF Data Flow?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

This is the functionality I am referring to in the title.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update

I was able to do it in Databricks using the Azure Cosmos DB OLTP Spark connector and I am wondering if the same is achievable in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no proper way do in azure dataflow as you done same in Databricks using the Azure Cosmos DB OLTP Spark connector.

Partial Document Update feature provides a convenient way to modify a document in a container. In data flow it takes all the document and consider it as whole data so you cannot perform changes for single document or single value It will do the changes in all documents and all values related to that key.

For more information. Please refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921548/azure-data-factory-pipeline-not-working-using-cosmos-db-while-we-use-derived-col) thread for demo.